# how to rename an existing file with today's date

Tags: shell, date, mv

I have a file `foo.c`. I want to rename it with today's date.
For example `foo1/10/14.c`
I tried using

```
 mv foo.c foo`date +%D`.c
```

but when i am doing it am getting an error

```
mv: cannot move `foo.c' to `foo01/10/14.c': No such file or directory
```

Maybe a script will do or some command in the terminal window. I'm using Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: It's trying to rename the file to `14.c` in a directory called `10` under a directory called `foo01`. Is that what you want?

Comment: no no .... i got my mistake ...  and i had corrected it .. its working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a file name cannot contain slashes `/`. When you indicate

```
mv foo.c foo`date +%D`.c
```

It internally does:

```
mv foo.c foo01/10/14.c
```

so it tries to move the file `foo.c` into `foo01/10` directory.

---

Instead, you can do:

```
date "+%F"
```

Which returns the date in a `2014-01-10` format and will expand into

```
mv foo.c foo2014-01-10.c
```